# Strange glyphs code error

Tags: errors, visual-editor, coding-standards

Recently I've noticed that just above the web page logo, strange glyphs appeared. What might be the cause? How to get rid of these.

Comment: Did you check your header.php file for example?

Comment: we don't have enough information to help here.  It looks likes its directly placed in.  When did this start?  Have you tried turning all plugins off and see if it disappears or changing themes?

Comment: Thanks, I've found the plugin which was the cause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is anything printed above the logo, then in most cases it's caused by some errors in PHP. So somewhere in your theme or in one of plugins there is some bad code that is causing this.

And these characters suggest that they're some badly converted UTF characters or some other characters that are not supported by your font.

From my experience - such problem occurs when site gets infected and malicious code is working not entirely how its author wanted it to...

So I would check your theme and then all other files of that site if they were modified and if they contain some code that doesn't look nice.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've found the plugin which was the cause.

Comment: I'd recommend to check what code was causing this and what that code was doing exactly.